# if formula change cells content formating

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have this problem in using if function ...

=IF(Izvještaj!I280>Izvještaj!I283;Mišljenja!A17;IF(Izvještaj!I280=Izvještaj!I283;Mišljenja!A17;IF(Izvještaj!I280

The content of original cell:

[image]

The content of cell after if function set it in place:

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include the `if` function you are using ...

Comment: Your formula do NOT changes the cell content. It recalculates new value and fully replaces previous, old, value. Of course Cell.Characters.Format for separate characters in this case is lost.

Comment: @ Máté Juhász - my formula choose betwen two text cells depending on a table results and sets it if it's true or not.

Comment: @ Akina - That formating of caracters in text is what i try to keep....

Comment: You can NOT store characters formatting while recalculating formula. Use VBA code for store formatting + set new value + restore formatting. The cell value must be stored as a literal, not as a formula, in this case, because any worksheet formula recalculation will destroy chars formatting again.

Answer (score 0):

> if formula change cells content formating

Excel has character level formatting only for constants.

There is no way to format parts of cell differently if value is the result of a formula, or to transfer format together with formula.

Comment: Thanks, that's what i have noticed but wasn't shure if there is a solution for it or no.